# unable to upload file in AWS s3 Bucket using Python Boto 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a file in S3 bucket using below script

```
import os
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
data = open('help.jpg','rb')
print(data)
s3.buckets('Whoos_bucket').put_object(key='Whoos_bucket',Body=data)
```

And getting below error

```
s3.buckets('Whoos_bucket').put_object(key='Whoos_bucket',Body=data)
TypeError: 's3.bucketsCollectionManager' object is not callable
```

Please note that above bucket exists and I am able to list it as well

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check the documentation? What you are looking for is `s3.Bucket`

```
s3.Bucket('Whoos_bucket').put_object(key='Whoos_bucket',Body=data)
```